# jQuery id selector is selecting all elements

Tags: jquery, express, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a ul with a specific id (todoItems) but all of the ul's on the page are being effecting by this code. Specifically the ul's in my navbar. I've tried selecting them by class as well with no luck. As I'm appending to a ul I couldn't think of a way to specifically select the li's. Any help is appreciated. See below for my code:

EDIT* This is the css for this as well. I'm running all of this code in an express app. I'm running this todo list on a page in this app with it's own navbar etc. The CSS/JS etc is linked using an ejs layout.

```js
var todoItems = document.getElementById("todoItems");

$(todoItems).on("click", ".todoItem", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

$(todoItems).on("click", "span.remove", function(event) {
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
  $(this).remove();
 });
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").on("keypress", function(event) {
 if (event.which === 13){
  var todoText = $(this).val();
  $(todoItems).append("<li class='todoItem'><span class = 'remove'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> </span>" + todoText + "</li>");
 }
});

$(".fa-plus").on("click", () => {
 $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #43515f;
}

.siteBody {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 background: #2980B9;  /* fallback for old browsers */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #FFFFFF, #6DD5FA, #2980B9);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #FFFFFF, #6DD5FA, #2980B9); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.siteBody h1 {
 background-color: #2980b9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
 color: #2980b9;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

input:focus {
 background-color: white;
 border: 3px solid #2980b9;
 outline: none;
}

.siteBody ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.siteBody li {
 background-color: white;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 color: #666;
}

.siteBody li:nth-child(2n) {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.siteBody li:hover span {
 width: 40px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.siteBody span {
 background-color: #e74c3c;
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 width: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 opacity: 0;
}

.fa-plus {
 float: right;
}

.completed {
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

#container {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 box-shadow: : 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 width: 360px;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Trey Cooper</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
  
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/posts/new">New Post</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/trey-cooper-8a231a123/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg white-text fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/cooper6101" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
<div class="container-fluid siteBody">
    <div id="container">
        <h1>TO-DO List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
        <input type="text" name="addTodo" placeholder="Add New Todo">
        <ul id="todoItems">
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Grocery Shop</li>
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Get coding job</li>
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Finish both Bootcamps</li>
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Walk Fish</li>
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cook Dinner</li>
            <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Book a flight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `$('#todoItems')`

Comment: I tried that initially but got the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Post your CSS as well. We need a [mcve] and I'm not seeing one.

Comment: Just added the css

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the way you set event listeners and removed the pure js way of selecting elements since you already use jQuery.

```js
$("#todoItems > .todoItem").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

$("#todoItems > span.remove").on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").on("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $("#todoItems").append("<li class='todoItem'><span class = 'remove'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> </span>" + todoText + "</li>");
  }
});

$(".fa-plus").on("click", () => {
  $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Trey Cooper</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/posts/new">New Post</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/trey-cooper-8a231a123/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg white-text fa-2x"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/cooper6101" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid siteBody">
  <div id="container">
    <h1>TO-DO List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" name="addTodo" placeholder="Add New Todo">
    <ul id="todoItems">
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Grocery Shop</li>
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Get coding job</li>
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Finish both Bootcamps</li>
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Walk Fish</li>
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cook Dinner</li>
      <li class="todoItem"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Book a flight</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much cleaner thank you. Unfortunately it's still causing the same problem. I'm running this code in an express app using layouts. I wonder if that could be causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
var todoItems = document.getElementById("todoItems");

    $(document).on("click", "#todoItems .todoItem", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("completed");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#todoItems span.remove", function(event) {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("input[type='text']").on("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            var todoText = $(this).val();
            $(todoItems).append("<li class='todoItem'><span class = 'remove'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> </span>" + todoText + "</li>");
        }
    });

    $(".fa-plus").on("click", () => {
        $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you but this is still not working. I'm running this code in an express app using layouts. I wonder if that could be causing my issue.